# Shortstack in table entries

Tags: tables

[image]

In order to optimize the width of some columns so that the table fits the text, I used `\shortstack`. Now, however, I am not satisfied with the look of the header (cf. picture). The header text in the columns in which I used `\shortstack` is now too close to the top hline. Furthermore, the headers where I didn't use `\shortstack` are not aligned to the top `\hline`, which they should. Is there a way to rectify this while using `\shortstack` or are there better solutions to adress the width of the columns?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
        \usepackage{tabulary}
        \usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{float,lscape}
        \usepackage{longtable}
       \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage{tabularx}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{bigstrut}

        \begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{ETV 1830 - 1930}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Year}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Organizations}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Associations}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Paying\\ members}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{in \% of total}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Non-paying\\ members}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{in \% of total}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Total\\ members}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Active\\ members}}} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    1830  & -     & 2     & -     & -     & -     & -     & -     & - \bigstrut[t]\\
    31-40 & -     & 7     & -     & -     & -     & -     & -     & - \\
   \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an effort to achieve your desired result with minimum changes to your original code, I added one line and changed another.  I first added the line `\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}` to have access to the `\addstackgap` macro.  Then, I modified your header row of the `tabular`, so that one of the cramped stacks was enclosed in an `\addstackgap`, such as `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\addstackgap{\textbf{\shortstack{Paying\\ members}}}}`.  This applies a 3pt vertical buffer around the object.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
        \usepackage{tabulary}
        \usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{float,lscape}
        \usepackage{longtable}
       \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage{tabularx}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{bigstrut}
        \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
        \begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{ETV 1830 - 1930}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Year}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Organizations}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Associations}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\addstackgap{\textbf{\shortstack{Paying\\ members}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{in \% of total}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Non-paying\\ members}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{in \% of total}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Total\\ members}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Active\\ members}}} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    1830  & -     & 2     & -     & -     & -     & -     & -     & - \bigstrut[t]\\
    31-40 & -     & 7     & -     & -     & -     & -     & -     & - \\
   \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Furthermore, if you desired the header row top-aligned, you can change every instance of `\shortstack` to `\Shortunderstack` (note the capital leading "S"), to obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can have what you want in a simpler way: the `makecell` package allows for line breaks in cells, and a common formatting (incl. vertical alignment) in specific table cells, thanks to the `\thead` and `\makecell` commands.
To have a better vertical spacing, simply use the `booktabs` package. Finally `caption`produces a correct vertical spacing between caption and table when the former is *above* the table, and you can customise further the caption.

Thus it is possible to have a table in `footnotesize` except for the column heads which are in `scriptsize` – instead of `tiny`, which almost unreadable:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{float,lscape}
    \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{bigstrut}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption, makecell, booktabs}
    \captionsetup{font = footnotesize}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\scriptsize}
    \renewcommand\theadalign{bc}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}
      \caption{ETV 1830 - 1930}
      \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
        \toprule
        \thead{Year} & \thead{Organizations} & \thead{Associations} & \thead{Paying\\ members} & \thead{in \%\\ of total} & \thead{Non-paying\\ members} & \thead{in \%\\ of total} & \thead{Total\\ members} & \thead{\shortstack{Active\\ members}}\\
        \midrule
        1830 & -- & 2 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
    \addlinespace
        31-40 & -- & 7 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
       \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ps. If you have the same problem but with regular cells instead of table heads, just use `\makecell` instead of `\thead`

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why you have in preamble packages which you don't use in your MWE. So I little bit rearrange your MWE and from all package use just `booktab` and `tabularx`. In tabularx for table width I select `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%        \usepackage{tabulary}
%        \usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
%        \usepackage{float,lscape}
%        \usepackage{longtable}
%       \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
%        \usepackage{multirow}
%        \usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \tiny
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\caption{ETV 1830 - 1930}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{9}{R}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Year}} 
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Organizations}} 
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Associations}} 
            &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Paying\\ members}}} 
                &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{in \%\\ of total}}}
                    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Non-paying\\ members}}} 
                        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{in \%\\ of total}}}
                            &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Total\\ members}}} 
                                &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\shortstack{Active\\ members}}} 
                                    \\
    \midrule
1830  & -     & 2     & -     & -     & -     & -     & -     & - \\
31-40 & -     & 7     & -     & -     & -     & -     & -     & - \\
   \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
    \end{document}
```

Edit: here is imege of table generated with above MWE.[image]